# Вывод среднего double числа в textBox

Tags: c#, windows, form

Есть два num, а именно:

```
double num1 = double.Parse(this.dataGridView1.Rows[acID].Cells[3].Value.ToString());
double num2 = double.Parse(this.textBox3.Text.ToString().Trim());
```

Как можно сделать так, чтоб при выпадении (неважно какого числа) в ячейке dataGridView1.Rows[acID].Cells[3], в поле textBox3, заданное там число менялось? Притом суть здесь вот в чем:
Допустим в textBox3 изначально я поставил число "0,69". А в ячейку dataGridView1.Rows[acID].Cells[3] выпало число например "9,34"(а оно там от 0,0 до 10,0 сек идет, после вновь с нуля считает). Надо сделать так, чтобы в textBox3 обозначилось новое число, в диапазоне: от старого числа "0,69" до выпавшего в ячейке "9,34".

Очень жаль что подобное нельзя совершить подобным кодом)) как:

```
Random z = new Random();
textBox3.Text = z.Next(num1, num2).ToString();
```

Comment: ничего не понял

Comment: Ну есть ячейка в dataGridView1.Rows, в ней от 0,00 сек до 10,00 сек идет отсчет. Когда до 10,00 сек дойдет счет, вновь он идет с 0,00 по новой. 
А  есть еще один textbox.text в котором стоит double значение допустим 0,69. Нужно, чтоб от в textBox.tex сменилось double число, в диапазоне: от старого double числа "0,69" до выпавшего в ячейке "9,34".

Я мог бы отправить видео, в котором более понятно что происходит в форме, чтоб понятнее стало, что я хочу

Comment: @ВикторХиман прикрепить картинку, больше кода и/или видео нельзя?

Comment: ну то есть да, верно. Но просто в каждой такой строке, есть ячейка, в которой и идет счет

Comment: Что такое "выпавшее"? Что такое "идет счет"? Вы оперируете известными только вам терминами.

Comment: В общем я попробую сейчас кусочек видео сюда прислать)

Comment: Лучше код покажите.

Comment: Прислал, во всяком случае то что выполняет отсчет в строке dataGridView и немного уже с самим textBox.text

Comment: хорошо спрошу так, не спорю что не ясно изъясняюсь, но все же, можно ли сделать нечто подобное:
'''
Random z = new Random();
textBox3.Text = z.Next(double num1, double num2).ToString();
'''
где double num1 - это изначальное значение в textbox3.text,
а double num2 - это одно из значений в dataGridView1.Rows[acID].Cells[3]

Comment: _кусочек видео прислать_ - не-не-не! Лучше рэпчик начитай!

Answer (score 0):

```cs
if (account.requestTime == 0L)
    {
      account.requestTime = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
    }
double num3 = ticks - account.requestTime;
this.dataGridView1.Rows[account.accountID].Cells[3].Value = Math.Round((double)(num3 / 10000000.0), 4).ToString(); 

    
 accounts[accountID].stoppedTime = DateTime.Now.Ticks;
 double num = 150.0;
   try
 {
   num = double.Parse(this.dataGridView1.Rows[accountID].Cells[3].Value.ToString());
 }
   catch (Exception exception1)
           {
                 Exception exception = exception1;
                 num = 150.0;
           }
double num2 = double.Parse(this.textBox3.Text.ToString().Trim());
```

Comment: При ответе на вопросы, давайте пояснения к вашему коду

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Добавьте пояснений от отформатируйте код. Читать невозможно.